What is wrong with the array. Returning Error "No viable alternative at input '[n {shuttles:'"
I've tried a few alternatives but end up getting even more errors.
"No viable alternative at input '[n {shuttles:'"
instinct2: extraneous input ',' expecting {'class', 'using', 'import', 'alias', 'typedef', 'public', 'private', 'protected', 'hidden', 'static', 'const', 'native', 'var', 'enum', 'function', '}', '('}
`class BeepTestApplicationView extends WatchUi.View {
var levelData;
var currentLevel;
var currentShuttle;
var countdown;
var beepTimer;
var levelStart;
var shuttleStart;

function initialize() {
    WatchUi.View.initialize();
    levelData = [
        { shuttles: 7, speed: 8.0, timePerShuttle: 9.00, levelTime: 63.0, distance: 140 },
        { shuttles: 8, speed: 9.0, timePerShuttle: 8.00, levelTime: 64.0, distance: 160 },
        { shuttles: 7, speed: 8.0, timePerShuttle: 9.00, levelTime: 63.0, distance: 140 },
        { shuttles: 8, speed: 9.0, timePerShuttle: 8.00, levelTime: 64.0, distance: 160 },
        { shuttles: 8, speed: 9.5, timePerShuttle: 7.58, levelTime: 60.6, distance: 160 },
        { shuttles: 9, speed: 10.0, timePerShuttle: 7.20, levelTime: 64.8, distance: 180 },
        { shuttles: 9, speed: 10.5, timePerShuttle: 6.86, levelTime: 61.7, distance: 180 },
        { shuttles: 10, speed: 11.0, timePerShuttle: 6.55, levelTime: 65.5, distance: 200 },
        { shuttles: 10, speed: 11.5, timePerShuttle: 6.26, levelTime: 62.6, distance: 200 },
        { shuttles: 11, speed: 12.0, timePerShuttle: 6.00, levelTime: 66.0, distance: 220 },
        { shuttles: 11, speed: 12.5, timePerShuttle: 5.76, levelTime: 63.4, distance: 220 },
        { shuttles: 11, speed: 13.0, timePerShuttle: 5.54, levelTime: 60.9, distance: 220 },
        { shuttles: 12, speed: 13.5, timePerShuttle: 5.33, levelTime: 64.0, distance: 240 },
        { shuttles: 12, speed: 14.0, timePerShuttle: 5.14, levelTime: 61.7, distance: 240 },
        { shuttles: 13, speed: 14.5, timePerShuttle: 4.97, levelTime: 64.6, distance: 260 },
        { shuttles: 13, speed: 15.0, timePerShuttle: 4.80, levelTime: 62.4, distance: 260 },
        { shuttles: 13, speed: 15.5, timePerShuttle: 4.65, levelTime: 60.4, distance: 260 },
        { shuttles: 14, speed: 16.0, timePerShuttle: 4.50, levelTime: 63.0, distance: 280 },
        { shuttles: 14, speed: 16.5, timePerShuttle: 4.36, levelTime: 61.1, distance: 280 },
        { shuttles: 15, speed: 17.0, timePerShuttle: 4.24, levelTime: 63.5, distance: 300 },
        { shuttles: 15, speed: 17.5, timePerShuttle: 4.11, levelTime: 61.7, distance: 300 },
        { shuttles: 16, speed: 18.0, timePerShuttle: 4.00, levelTime: 64.0, distance: 320 },
        { shuttles: 16, speed: 18.5, timePerShuttle: 3.89, levelTime: 62.3, distance: 320 }
    ];
    currentLevel = 0;
    currentShuttle = 0;
    countdown = 5;
    beepTimer = 0;
    levelStart = false;
    shuttleStart = false;
    draw();
}

I've tried all the super basic stuff I can see, like extraneous characters but no luck. Help appreciated!

It seems that Garmin uses a programming language "Monkey C", which seems does not support constructs like [{...}, {...}, ...] see https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/monkey-c/containers/ and https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/monkey-c/monkey-types/
